# Is there a way to convert a Bash script into a GUI Application?

Tags: bash, user-interface, ubuntu

I have written a fully functioning bash script performing a proxy switching within a Local Area Network based on relative speeds.

Can I convert this directly into a GUI application for Ubuntu? If not where should I start (I am completely new to GUI App development)?

Can this script be converted into any other language?

Comment: what do you mean by an "Ubuntu application"?

Comment: like any music player or something that need not just run inside a terminal ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need only create a "desktop" file for it, and place it in `~/.local/share/applications/`.

The easiest way to do that is using [MenuLibre](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/menulibre/). Incidentally, there's nothing Ubuntu-specific about this. The same trick will work with most distros.

If you want your script to have a task-bar icon, or open dialog windows, or show a desktop notification bubble, you might like to look at [Zenity](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/zenity/).

Of course you can rewrite your script in any other language you choose, but I'm not aware of an easy way to convert it automatically.

Comment: I installed menulibre and was able create a desktop image of my script.. But then when i try to run it ubuntu reports an internal server error.. What changes does the application expect to run?? When run in terminal it simply outputs data to stdout... no user input coz i want it to automatically detect faster proxy and change to it... Please suggest me what code does the application expect

Comment: Did you check the box "run in a terminal"?

Comment: thanks a lot .this was really useful. zenity is really a cool way to convert scripts to apps. how to add this applicaiton to desktop menu bar I searched but in vain ??

Comment: The "zenity --notification" thing used to add an icon the top bar. When I try it now it seems to open and OK/Cancel box instead. Very strange! Maybe it's a Unity thing? :(

Comment: If you mean, how to add it to the Unity launcher, on the left, then you have to find your app in the pop-up dash, and drag the icon to the left.

Comment: Actually when i run my application ,it says "failed to execute child process "proxy_selector" (No such file or directory found)" ... I added the paths to my bashrc files... it works perfectly fine from the terminal ...Wt could be the possible mistake??

Comment: It probably doesn't use your bashrc script in that mode; that's usually only for interactive shell sessions. You could add it to your .profile file, log out and log in, maybe.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help... I have finally successfully converted my script into an Ubuntu Application...